# How do I connect the various pieces of my Web API Castle Windsor DI code?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api-routing

How do I connect the various pieces of my Web API Castle Windsor DI code so that the Controller's routing selects the correct interface implementation?

**Note**: After several false starts/dead ends and partial victories ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20843810/how-can-i-incorporate-this-castle-windsor-di-code-into-my-controller-and-reposit) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860732/how-do-i-specify-the-class-instance-i-want-my-controllers-constructor-to-receiv) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20846691/where-is-the-magic-happening-when-a-controller-instantiates-the-correct-implem)), I am going to bountify this ASAP for the maximum **500** points. But I'm only going to award a really good answer - IOW, one that is clear enough that I can understand it and "plug it in" to my project so that I can hook a given concrete class to a particular Controller.

Here goes nothing: I have a Web API ("MVC") project. Really, though, this server project has no "V" (View), so maybe a better acronym would be MRC (Model/Repository/Controller).

At any rate, I'm trying to add DI to it using Castle Windsor.

I grok, and dig, the concept of swapping out concrete classes via constructor interface args. Just how to implement this functionality, though,

has been a beast I've been wrestling with, and I'm quite bruised and bloody at present, with mussed-up hair and mud-encrusted nostrils to boot.

I have, I think, most of the code I need - to start with, anyway. With DI in mind, I've now got a "DIPlumbing" folder, and a "DIInstallers" folder. 
The "DIPlumbing" folder contains two classes:  WindsorCompositionRoot.cs, and WindsorControllerFactory.cs.

The "DIInstallers" folder has, for now, three files, namely ISomethingProvider.cs, SomethingProvider.cs, and SomethingProviderInstaller.cs

SomethingProviderInstaller seems to be key in connecting the interfaces/classes in DIInstallers to the stuff in the DIPlumbing folder.

(I have also modified Global.asax.cs to replace the default controller routing business with the Castle Windsor replacement).

But I'm confused as to what classes I should be placing in the DIInstallers folder. Are these supposed to take the place of my Repositories (which likewise have an interface and a concrete class that implements that interface for each model)? IOW, should I basically move my Repository code into the DIInstallers folder - and then get rid of the IRepository and Repository units?

This, of course, would cause necessary changes to be made in the Controller classes, which as of now reference Repository classes.

Or do the Repositories and DIInstallers classes coexist? If so, what is the connection/affiliation between the Controllers, Installers, and Repositories?

It seems the more I read up on DI and Castle Windsor, the more confused I get. I don't know if I'm too dense for it, or if I'm trying to make it harder than it is, or if conflicting styles of using/presenting it are the problem. The bottom line is: I'm stuck in quicksand and need Johnny Quest to extend a sturdy bamboo rod.

The best answer of all, perhaps, and probably too much to ask for, would be a visual representation of how all these components - Controllers, Models, Repositories, Installers, Global.asax.cs, composition roots, factories, providers, etc., relate to each other.

For purposes of "full disclosure," I will add what I hope are the key elements of my code below to show what I've got and how it (hopefully) connects to each other.

**Composition Root:**

```
public class WindsorCompositionRoot : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IWindsorContainer container;

    public WindsorCompositionRoot(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
        Type controllerType)
    {
        var controller =
            (IHttpController)this.container.Resolve(controllerType);

        request.RegisterForDispose(
            new Release(
                () => this.container.Release(controller)));

        return controller;
    }

    private class Release : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Action release;

        public Release(Action release)
        {
            this.release = release;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.release();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller Factory:**

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;
        //According to my understanding of http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility.ashx, I might need this:
        kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
        }
        return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }
```

// Note: The "Something" below will hopefully eventually be "Departments" and then other classes now represented in Models and their corresponding Repositories and Controllers

**ISomethingProvider:**

```
public interface ISomethingProvider
{
    // These are placeholder methods; I don't know which I will need yet...
    //bool Authenticate(string username, string password, bool createPersistentCookie);
    //void SignOut();
}
```

**SomethingProvider:**

```
public class SomethingProvider : ISomethingProvider
{
    // TODO: Implement methods in ISomethingProvider, once they have been added
}
```

**SomethingProviderInstaller:**

```
public class SomethingProviderInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                               .BasedOn(typeof(ISomethingProvider))
                               .WithServiceAllInterfaces());
        // From http://app-code.net/wordpress/?p=676; see also http://devlicio.us/blogs/krzysztof_kozmic/archive/2009/12/24/castle-typed-factory-facility-reborn.aspx
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
        container.Register(Component.For<IMyFirstFactory>().AsFactory()); 
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class DepartmentsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IDepartmentRepository _deptsRepository;

    public DepartmentsController(IDepartmentRepository deptsRepository)
    {
        if (deptsRepository == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("deptsRepository is null");
        }
        _deptsRepository = deptsRepository;
    }

    public int GetCountOfDepartmentRecords()
    {
        return _deptsRepository.Get();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Department> GetBatchOfDepartmentsByStartingID(int ID, int CountToFetch)
    {
        return _deptsRepository.Get(ID, CountToFetch);
    }
. . .
}
```

**IRepository:**

```
public interface IDepartmentRepository
{
    int Get();
    IEnumerable<Department> Get(int ID, int CountToFetch);
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public class DepartmentRepository : IDepartmentRepository
{
    private readonly List<Department> departments = new List<Department>();

    public DepartmentRepository()
    {
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;[bla]"))
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT td_department_accounts.dept_no, IIF(ISNULL(t_accounts.name),'No Name provided',t_accounts.name) AS name FROM t_accounts INNER JOIN td_department_accounts ON t_accounts.account_no = td_department_accounts.account_no ORDER BY td_department_accounts.dept_no";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                conn.Open();
                int i = 1;
                using (OleDbDataReader oleDbD8aReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (oleDbD8aReader != null && oleDbD8aReader.Read())
                    {
                        int deptNum = oleDbD8aReader.GetInt16(0);
                        string deptName = oleDbD8aReader.GetString(1);
                        Add(new Department { Id = i, AccountId = deptNum, Name = deptName });
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int Get()
    {
        return departments.Count;
    }

    private Department Get(int ID) // called by Delete()
    {
        return departments.First(d => d.Id == ID);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Department> Get(int ID, int CountToFetch)
    {
        return departments.Where(i => i.Id > ID).Take(CountToFetch);
    }
. . .
}
```

**Global.asax.cs:**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private static IWindsorContainer container;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        BootstrapContainer();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    private static void BootstrapContainer()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());
        var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);

        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(
            typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new WindsorCompositionRoot(container));
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }
```

### UPDATE

In trying to run the server, so that it could test it with Fiddler2 to see just what is being passed around, it failed on this line in WindsorControllerFactory:

```
public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
{
    this.kernel = kernel;
    kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>(); <-- throws exception here
}
```

...with "*System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Facility of type 'Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryFacility' has already been registered with the container. Only one facility of a given type can exist in the container.
  Source=Castle.Windsor
  StackTrace:
       at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(String key, IFacility facility)
       at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacility(IFacility facility)
       at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.AddFacilityT
       at HandheldServer.DIPlumbing.WindsorControllerFactory..ctor(IKernel kernel) in c:\HandheldServer\HandheldServer\DIPlumbing\WindsorControllerFactory.cs:line 28
       at HandheldServer.WebApiApplication.BootstrapContainer() in c:\HandheldServer\HandheldServer\Global.asax.cs:line 69
       at HandheldServer.WebApiApplication.Application_Start() in c:\HandheldServer\HandheldServer\Global.asax.cs:line 39*"

### UPDATE 2

In response to Cristiano's answer:

So are you saying I should add the following two files to my Installers folder (I do have a DIInstallers folder already)

PlatypusInstallerFactory.cs:

```
public class PlatypusInstallerFactory : InstallerFactory
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> Select(IEnumerable<Type> installerTypes)
    {
        var windsorInfrastructureInstaller = installerTypes.FirstOrDefault(it => it == typeof(WindsorInfrastructureInstaller));

        var retVal = new List<Type>();
        retVal.Add(windsorInfrastructureInstaller);
        retVal.AddRange(installerTypes
            .Where(it =>
                typeof(IWindsorInstaller).IsAssignableFrom(it) &&
                !retVal.Contains(it)
                ));

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

WindsorInfrastructureInstaller.cs:

```
public class WindsorInfrastructureInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    }
}
```

In your global.asax you'll create&use you installer factory as following

```
   var installerFactory = new PlatypusInstallerFactory();
   container.Install(FromAssembly.This(installerFactory));
```

If yes, what will that do for me? Does the above automagically register my Controller and/or Repository classes?

### UPDATE 3

I am now using a lot of code from [http://blog.kerbyyoung.com/2013/01/setting-up-castle-windsor-for-aspnet.html#comment-form]

The key parts are, I think:

**global.asax.cs:**

```
private static IWindsorContainer _container;

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    ConfigureWindsor(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}

public static void ConfigureWindsor(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
    _container = new WindsorContainer();
    _container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
    _container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(_container.Kernel, true));
    var dependencyResolver = new WindsorDependencyResolver(_container);
    configuration.DependencyResolver = dependencyResolver;
}
```

**WindsorDependencyResolver.cs:**

```
namespace HandheldServer
{
    public class WindsorDependencyResolver : System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

        public WindsorDependencyResolver(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        public IDependencyScope BeginScope()
        {
            return new WindsorDependencyScope(_container);
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (!_container.Kernel.HasComponent(serviceType))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return this._container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (!_container.Kernel.HasComponent(serviceType))
            {
                return new object[0];
            }

            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType).Cast<object>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _container.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public class WindsorDependencyScope : IDependencyScope
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;
        private readonly IDisposable _scope;

        public WindsorDependencyScope(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            this._container = container;
            this._scope = container.BeginScope(); 
        }

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (_container.Kernel.HasComponent(serviceType))
            {
                return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return this._container.ResolveAll(serviceType).Cast<object>();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this._scope.Dispose();
        }
    }

    public class ApiControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container, Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly() // should it be Types instead of Classes?
             .BasedOn<ApiController>()
             .LifestylePerWebRequest());
        }
    }

    // This idea from https://github.com/argeset/set-locale/blob/master/src/client/SetLocale.Client.Web/Configurations/IocConfig.cs
    public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IDeliveryItemRepository>().ImplementedBy<DeliveryItemRepository>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IDeliveryRepository>().ImplementedBy<DeliveryRepository>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IDepartmentRepository>().ImplementedBy<DepartmentRepository>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IExpenseRepository>().ImplementedBy<ExpenseRepository>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IInventoryItemRepository>().ImplementedBy<InventoryItemRepository>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IInventoryRepository>().ImplementedBy<InventoryRepository>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
                Component.For<IItemGroupRepository>().ImplementedBy<ItemGroupRepository>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 4

[This question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223545/what-am-i-missing-in-my-misunderstanding-of-ioc-di-castle-windsor) is probably too general for SO, so I posted it on "Programmers"

### UPDATE 5

Note: According to "The DI Whisperer" (Mark Seemann), IDependencyResolver should not be used, because it lacks a Release method (p. 207 of his book)

Comment: Is Castle Windsor an absolute requirement? I've had a similar project, using web api controllers with no view, and have been using Ninject. Easy to set up and does what I need it to. Is there anything that CW does that an alternative such as Ninject couldn't?

Comment: Yes, Castle Windsor is the company standard.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon you're calling `kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>()` in 2 places (`SomethingProviderInstaller` and `WindsorControllerFactory`) and the definition of `IMyFirstFactory` is missing.

Comment: @Shannon you are working for company w/ great standard :-)

Comment: @qujck: I was only calling kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility> in one place, and it is now commented out. Thanks, I commented out "IMyFirstFactory" now, too.

Comment: @qujck: You were partly right; I was also calling container.AddFacility() elsewhere; I've now commented that out, too.

Comment: If you could send out the code(solution) it'd be much easier to find and fix the problem.

Comment: @realnero: You need more than what I've posted above? If so, what, exactly?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I mean zip file with complete solution if possible

Comment: Are file attachments allowed here? I could do that, but I'd have to remove some of the database connection stuff.

Comment: @realnero: I realized that some of my code has changed since the previous posts, so I added an Update 3.

Comment: @realnero: I realized what you meant; my question is, where do I put it? Does SO allow file uploads?

Comment: Asked a related question on Programmers at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223545/what-am-i-missing-in-my-misunderstanding-of-ioc-di-castle-windsor

Comment: @B.ClayShannon upload it somewhere like Dropbox or any other online storage.

Comment: Here it is: filedropper.com/handheldserverbackup

Comment: +1 for the very long question which I will forget its beginning before I reach its end :LOL how long did it took you to write it :D

Comment: @MuhammadNour: Why do you put it in the past tense? I'm still writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't want to repeat everything again, so just check out my answer on [How do I get Web API / Castle Windsor to recognize a Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960690/how-do-i-get-web-api-castle-windsor-to-recognize-a-controller/20970371#20970371).

As another note - I would advise against doing anything in your repository constructors if you can help it. The reason I say this is that the constructors get called as Windsor is trying to instantiate the correct instance of your repository. What this means is that if any kind of error occurs, it happens as WebApi is trying to create the controller. This can make it a bit tricky to track down the problem sometimes, and also ends up hiding the real issues under tons of layers of exceptions.

Comment: Thanks; I don't have the bounty button anymore here; maybe it expired. I did add a 500 point bounty to the other question/answer, though, that I will award you tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

You should not mix installation vs resolving.
IOW your should not have

```
kernel.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
```

in the WindsorControllerFactory

But the generic container configuration such registering TypedFactoryFacility should be executed in an installer called as earlier as possible.

In order to drive installer execution, you should use an Installer factory

```
public class YourInstallerFactory : InstallerFactory
{
    public override IEnumerable<Type> Select(IEnumerable<Type> installerTypes)
    {
        var windsorInfrastructureInstaller = installerTypes.FirstOrDefault(it => it == typeof(WindsorInfrastructureInstaller));

        var retVal = new List<Type>();
        retVal.Add(windsorInfrastructureInstaller);
        retVal.AddRange(installerTypes
            .Where(it =>
                typeof(IWindsorInstaller).IsAssignableFrom(it) &&
                !retVal.Contains(it)
                ));

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Where windsorInfrastructureInstaller will be somenthing like this

```
public class WindsorInfrastructureInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        // Resolvers
        //container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new ArrayResolver(container.Kernel));

        // TypedFactoryFacility
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
    }
}
```

In your global.asax you'll create&use you installer factory as following

```
 var installerFactory = new YourInstallerFactory();
 container.Install(FromAssembly.This(installerFactory));
```

Your "FrontEnd"(for example the mvc/webapi) project has a folder containing all installers(WindsorInfrastructureInstaller will be one of those) and the installer factory as well or at least that's the way I'm use to organize my solution.

Comment: Thanks, Cristiano; can you show a screenshot of the Solution Explorer that would depict where these classes belong - which folders are standard? IOW, showing where the YourInstallerFactory and the WindsorInfrastructureInstaller classes should be?

Comment: Actually, our front end is a handheld device - it will pass URIs to the CastleWindsorified Web API server app and expect json results back.

Comment: In your case, what I call "front end" prj is the webapi server and there is the place where you place installer & factory I mentioned above same as the container and any other classes depending on windsor classes

Comment: If that's the front end, what is the back end? The Web API server project sends data to the client, so...???

Comment: That's just a matter of naming -:)  I call "front end" the more external prj on the server side. IOW the prj that provides any kind of output such json/api or an mvc

Comment: A rose by any other name still smells as sweet; I still don't want to call a rose a frumious bandersnatch, though.

Comment: Fair enough! Beside naming, is there anything else I may help you out on this matter? As I said, you should place the installers&their factory in the webapi prj / mvc / console / wpf. Someone puts installer also in class library prj, but I prefer to have windsor reference only on the main prj. I cannot provide you a screen shot of our solution, but if you put a sample on git, I'll be happy to review it and comment on the reference/structure

Comment: "you should place the installers&their factory in the webapi prj" EVERYTHING I've shown is in my Web API project.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44902/discussion-between-cristiano-degiorgis-and-b-clay-shannon)

Comment: I think I uploaded the project to https://github.com/bclayshannon/WebAPICastleWindsorExtravaganza

Comment: Okay, it wasn't obvious to me how to use it; I'll try to put it somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to my own question, I would simply say: There are no shortcakes! Without stopping go or further ado, [go here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182501) and get this book. Resign yourself to take the time necessary to read it carefully.

So I'm not the only one; here's a quote from Jeff Beck, who wrote that book's foreword: "*Often those who start using DI quickly find themselves lost in a sea of confusion.*"

Comment: This is indeed the definitive work on the subject, in my opinion.